# Magento 2 V1/Shipment API getParentItem on null

Tags: orders, magento2.2.2, rest-api, shipment

I am using postman the rest api to create shipping:

http://myMagento/rest/default/V1/shipment

POST:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "order_id": 5873,
    "shipment_status": 1,
    "store_id": 1,
    "total_qty": 3,
    "items": [
      {
        "parent_id": 5873,
        "price": 4.99,
        "product_id": 3964,
        "row_total": 3.49,
        "sku": "2457-0000",
        "weight": 1.25,
        "order_item_id": 3964,
        "qty": 3
      }
    ],
    "tracks": [
      {
        "order_id": 5873,
        "weight": 1.25,
        "qty": 3,
        "description": "Tracking Updated",
        "track_number": "123456",
        "title": "DHL",
        "carrier_code": "DHL"
      }
    ],
    "comments": [
      {
        "is_customer_notified": 1,
        "comment": "Order Completed",
        "is_visible_on_front": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone help with the above it creates the shipping fine but when click action view the error shows:
Is this something to do with parent_id inside items ? what would be the parent_id here?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getParentItem() 
on null in 
.../vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/view/items.phtml:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parent_id` of the shipment item is the `entity_id` of the shipment and if I understand you correctly you create a new shipment with this request. So you can't now the `entity_id` of the newly created shipment at that time.

I would suggest to remove the `parent_id` from the item. The only required fields in the API documentation inside the items array are `order_item_id` and `qty` - everything else is optional. I guess the other fields like sku, price etc. will anyway be taken from the corresponding order_item.

Comment: Thanks I found where the problem is! the `order_item_id` it isn't the `order_id` or the `product_id` it should the `item_id` from table `sales_order_item` I was basically trying with `entity_id` from `sales_order` table which isn't right and yes you are right you don't need to send all the detail but some fields in the shipping grid like `ship-to-name` wont show.

Comment: That's right, from your question I didn't realize that it's not clear to you that the `order_item_id` is the id of the order item and not of the order :-). But you have anyway to remove the parent_id otherwise you will have strange data constellations.